# SQL/NoSQL Database Management System with asynchronous C++ driver

Tags: c++, database, asynchronous

I am going to write a high-performance restful API server based on restbed(C++ framework), but neither MySQL nor MongoDB has asynchronous C++ driver. Could you advise a database management system with asynchronous C++ driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL community is [working](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-execution.html) towards an asynchronous C++ connector, however it's not there yet.  There are multiple sources of information regarding the asynchronous C API:

1. http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/
2. http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=14757
3. https://github.com/chkpk/mysql-async-example
4. http://blog.pdani.org/2011/12/making-asynchronous-mysql-queries-in-c.html
5. http://www.google.co.uk

And [MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/src/mongoc/mongoc-async.c).

Alternatives:

- [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/using-the-non-blocking-library/) - offshoot of MySQL
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-async.html)